# SQL Server Agent error - Connection "DatabaseName" is not found?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

Some modifications were made to an SSIS package and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. The SQL server agent job which involves execution of one of these packages was running fine until a couple of days ago. The error I am seeing is this...

> Executed as user: domainname\serviceaccount. ... for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  4:47:33 PM  Error: 2010-07-07 16:47:34.09     Code: 0xC001000E     Source: PackageNAME Description: The connection "DB.NAME" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.  End Error  Warning: 2010-07-07 16:47:34.09     Code: 0x8001F02F     Source: PackageNAME Description: Cannot resolve a package path to an object in the package ".Connections[DB.NAME].Properties[ConnectionString]". Verify that the package path is valid.  End Warning  Warning: 2010-07-07 16:47:34.09     Code: 0x80012017     Source: PackageNAME Description: The package path referenced an object that cannot be found: "\Package.Connections[DB.NAME].Properties[ConnectionString]". This occurs when an attempt is made to resolve a package ...  The package executed successf...  The step succeeded.

I did not get any alerts that the job had an error because as the last line suggested, the step succeeded. Because of this, the job did not run "properly" for a few days and I'm scratching my head as to what may be the problem. Has anyone seen this error before?

Answer (score 0):

The dts job step has variables and variable values it associates with the SSIS package.  In SQL 2008, SQL Agent, Jobs, Job, Steps, Job Step Properties.  There are a set of tabs.   Each has influence on how the package runs.  For instance, the Data Sources tab allows you to change the connection string to any of your data sources.  Here's one guess - there's a connection named "DB.NAME" which is defined in the job, but not in the SSIS package.

Anyways, if you made significant changes, try recreating the job from the SSIS package and see if that doesn't solve your problem.